# Connect two Docker Containers via SocketIO

Tags: docker, http, socket.io

I have multiple Docker Containers (Server, Client, AI) running on the same Docker bridge. I want the AI to connect to the Server in order to exchange information with Socket.io.
However, when I try to connect the AI to to the Server via:

```
sio = socketio.Client()

def main():
    sio.connect('http://localhost:4000')
    sio.emit('ConnectAI', "TEST")
    sio.wait()

print("Setting up Connection...")
time.sleep(10)
asyncio.run(main())
```

I get an Error saying

> socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4000): Max retries exceeded with url: /socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4&t=1659336255.2636092 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f87b70dc7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

I don't know why the connection gets refused. The machines run on the same network, they both use the same version of socketIO.

Here is my Docker-Compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

  ai:
    build:
      context: ./ai
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

And here is my Server Docker:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:14.20.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000
CMD npm start
```

And my AI Docker:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app



COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .


EXPOSE 5000

CMD python3 connection.py
```

Comment: Why do you try to connect to localhost? If your socket.io server is running in `server`, connect to `server`.

Comment: The server has open port 4000, I am trying to connect to that. What exactly do you mean by connecting to server directly?

Comment: `http://server:4000`

Comment: Docker Containers are different machines. Accessing localhost:4000 on AI machine tries to make a connection to AI on port 4000. And there is nothing running on that machine listening to port 4000. 

If you have all machines in 1 docker-compose file, then you can access them by service name: http://server:4000.
And if you have different docker-compose files, then you need to set up an external docker-network and access them via IP4 addresses. 

Also, if you access the Server only from other Docker Container, then you don't even need the Ports section in the docker-compose.